# Can the visibility of contents on IPFS be restricted?

Tags: p2p, distributed-system, ipfs

Is it possible to restrict some contents on IPFS based on certain group privileges?

From what I have gathered from my readings is - once you deploy a content, it generates a hash based on the content and it is accessible from anywhere.

Suppose an organization wants to expose certain confidential files deployed on IPFS to only the members of that organization, is it possible to achieve this in the current implementation of IPFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually IPFS doesn't implement an access control system, but you can implement a such mechanism based on Cryptography, take a look about "[Cryptree](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4032481)" mechanism.

Comment: Thanks but "Cryptree" seems to be more of a proposed research/thesis project rather than a real world implementation. I was actually looking for more of sth that had practical usage.

Comment: Yes, But you can inspire from cryptree to implement an easier mecansime; using encryption algorithms.  For example to share a file with Alice, encrypt the file using Alice public key and store it in IPFS